# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' in using $.getJSON() function

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

i have an external JS file which is loading data from JSON using `$.getJSON`

```
(function() {
    var url = "dummy.json";
    $.getJSON( url,
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        })
});
```

Whenever i load my html page related to this script, i am constantly getting this error in the console

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'    .done(function( data ) {

My question is-  What is the cause of my problem here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) syntax. Missing `)` after `url`. **Should be** `$.getJSON( url ).done(..`

Comment: @Tushar.... Still getting the same error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a syntax error. You should chain `.done()` on a request.

```
(function() {
    var url = "dummy.json";
    $.getJSON( url, function(){
         console.log('done something');

        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log('something went wrong');    
        });

});
```

Comment: If i ommit 2nd argument of getJSON and chain ".done" with url like this- $.getJSON(url).done(...) would it be a problem ? My syntax error hase gone by using this but couldn't load the JSON data.

Comment: Yeah. that should be okay.

Comment: Just asking, it would be helpful for me. I am still not able to load JSON data, that means nothing is showing in console.log.

Comment: @ni8mr Are you sure the source of JSON is actually providing the data?

Comment: @ni8mr Can you try doing the same using `$.ajax` ?

Comment: `$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});` Here `success` is the callback method called on success.

Comment: Ajax is also not loading. May be there is problem in url or dummy.json. Both dummy.json and selection.js is in the same level in the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, normally it requires a default  callback method as below I suppose:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
```